# Апостроф у кросвордах

Tags: вживання-слів

Чи вживаються слова з апострофом в україномовних кросвордах? Якщо так, то чи займає апостроф окрему клітинку?

Answer (score 5):

[Коментар користувача Дмитро в темі «Як бути з апострофом у кросворді?» на форумі СЛОВНИКа.ua](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?s=&showtopic=2112&view=findpost&p=11210):

> Кросворди складаються за тими самими правилами, що й словники. Тому брати до уваги апостроф не слід. Не знаю, чи є щодо цього якісь спеціальні правила, але це давня традиція української преси (принаймні тої, яку я передплачував колись). Сучасних видань з українськими кросвордами не так-то й багато. Але газети "Молодь України" та "Україна молода" додержують словникового принципу.

Оскільки «складаються за тими самими правилами, що й словники» можна зрозуміти по-різному, поясню, як я це розумію. При сортуванні слів у словниках апостроф не інтерпретується як окрема літера, що має фіксоване місце в абетці (перед А, після Я чи ще десь), а просто ігнорується. Приклад зі [«Словників України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/):
***в'ю**рок*
*<…>*
***вю**ртемберзький*
*<…>*
***в'ю**чак*
(як бачимо, *вю*- йде впереміш із *в'ю-*, а точний порядок визначається рештою слова: *-рок*, *-ртемберзький*, *-чак*).

Хоча Дмитро не навів конретних прикладів кросвордів, де на апостроф не виділялась би клітина, але мені така позиція здається логічною.

Припускаю, що така сама ситуація з дефісом. Також припускаю, що укладачі кросвордів можуть уникати слів з апострофом і дефісом, щоб у читача не виникало зайвих проблем. Або іноді можуть, навпаки, давати підказку читачу в таких випадках, якось так (це моє припущення, це не з реального кросворду):

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |ʼ  |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+
| М |ʼЯ | С | О |
+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |  -|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| Ф | О | Р | С-| М | А | Ж | О | Р |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: [Приклад](http://izbornyk.org.ua/rizne/norm29.htm) проблеми  (переважно на межі словотвору): з’ява (зйава), але зява (зьава в риби)

Comment: @stegetsj, так, згоден. Але ж кросворд і не мусить вимагати повної однозначності, це річ для розваги, він може бути поблажливим («хоч якось вписав — і добре»).

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю щодо вживання у кросвордах. Але, на мою думку, логічним є використання для апострофа окремої клітинки.

Поясню свою думку.

Апостроф - це графічний знак, що не позначає звука. Але він впливає на вимову слова. Наприклад, зявитися і з'явитися. Коли читатиме українець ці два слова за правилами, то вимова буде різною. А отже присутність цього знака є важливою.

Х.З.У., що вимова слова зявитися без апострофа є незвичною.

Comment: Чи можете навести якісь приклади кросвордів, де є слово з апострофом? І що означає Х.З.У.?

Comment: Х.З.У. - хочу звернути увагу.

Comment: Вибачте, приклад навести не можу.

Comment: На початку повідомлення написав: "Не знаю щодо вживання у кросвордах.".